# can I send SMS without installed sim card in phone through my android app?

Tags: android, sms

I want to send SMS from my android app.In this App I dont want to use currently installed sim card in my phone.I want to use other sim card which is not installed.Also I dont want to used any APIs.is it possible or not? If its possible then please tell me that how I do that.

Comment: I don't think this one possible.Android hardware level it is not supported.

Comment: ok..Thx..@ Sajith4U..I want to just know that it is possible or not...I think it is not possible.

Comment: It is impossible. But, we can send through third party sms based app. for this u need to registered with ur mobile no. ( Example: waytosms.com)

Comment: @iffu...Thax for your response.I'll try to make it.